# Can't use htaccess while in a simple mvc project

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

After I defined the controllers and one method to use and `htaccess` file inside controller folder with this code:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

when I use this address in browser

> localhost/projectmvc/index.php?url=nextpage

the result is:
we are in index page
nextpage

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

but when I enter this address of

> localhost/projectmvc/index/mypage

I expected to have this result:

we are in index page `index/mypage`

but what I get as result is:

we are in index page

```
Notice:Undefined index:url in E:\xampp\htdocs\projectmvc\index.php on line 9
```

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

`index.php` code

```
echo ('we are in index page <br>');
echo $_GET['url'];
```

thanks in Advance

Comment: Is the PhpStorm tag relevant? I mean, is it an issue that only happens when you launch your app from the IDE?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `localhost/projectmvc/mypage`? Without the `/index` part?

Comment: i actually do not run thru IDE , just will type at address bar of browser like localhost/projectmvc/    @Alvaro Gonzalez

Comment: @kerbholz i want to send whatever comes after projectmvc/   as a text to another php file which i defined in htaccess like  when i have this address localhost/projectmvc/xx/yy   then i will have  "xx/yy" as a querystring or text in php file same i defined already then later i will use them as controller and methos.